# Установка git на android

Tags: git

Подскажите, как установить git на android и куда писать команды, чтобы им пользоваться? Или же нужно чем-то его заменить, но чем? И как этим чем-то пользоваться?

Comment: Например в Termux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Тебе надо скачать termux, потом выполнить эту команду для установки git'а

```
pkg update && pkg install git
```

Гайд по установку termux на android и на ios:
https://teletype.in/@artur.kerimov777/LULi6jK5-

Comment: А как подключить установленный git к среде разработки?

Comment: @DenisZotkin к сожалению я не могу дать вам ответ, так-как я не знаю ответа